# Webform Civicrm contribution multisite domain 2 drupal

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, contributions

I have a Drupal site setup as a civicrm multisite on domain 2 using webforms civicrm module to build registration pages, it was all working in development. Once it was connected to the live civicrm and the submissions of the form at the point of sagepay now logs an error.

The CiviCRM "contribution create" API returned the error: "DB Error: syntax error" when called by function "preSave" on line 163 of wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc

It also fails to redirect to sagepay but instead returns the thank you page.

Comment: have you duplicated the webform so that you can test this on the other domains? is everything directly 'in civi' working fine for both/all domains?

Comment: Yes it works in civi for both domains and Drupal's permissions are set to allow webform access.